Lee's Smooth Manifolds Question 8-12 - Pushforwards of Vector Fields
EDIT: I have posted the solution as an answer. The things I have written below in the question have errors.
I am wondering if I have approached this question correctly from Lee's Smooth Manifolds. Specifically, to show a vector field exists, is all I would need to show that the pushforwards are smooth in each chart and for example don't include a term of 1/x?

(Exercise 8-12) Let $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^2$ be the
smooth map $F(x, y)=[x, y, 1]$, and let $X \in$
$\mathfrak{X}\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)$ be defined by $X=x \partial /
 \partial y-y \partial / \partial x$. Prove that there is a vector
field $Y \in \mathfrak{X}\left(\mathbb{R P}^2\right)$ that is
$F$-related to $X$, and compute its coordinate representation in terms
of each of the charts defined in Example 1.5.


There are three charts on $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$. They are
$$\varphi_1([x,y,z])=\left(\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z}\right)$$
$$\varphi_2([x,y,z])=\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{z}{y}\right)$$
$$\varphi_3([x,y,z])=\left(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x}\right).$$
We compute $F_*X$ in the first chart. Let $q=[x,y,1]$. Then
$$
F_*X
=d_{F^{-1}(q)}F(X_{F^{-1}(q)})
=x\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_{(x,y)}-\left.y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y)}
 $$
Now the transition map between $\varphi_1$ coordinates and $\varphi_2$ coordinates is
$$(x,y) \mapsto\left(\frac{x}{y}, \frac{1}{y}\right)=(\tilde x, \tilde y).$$
Now we convert to $(\tilde x, \tilde y)$ coordinates.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_{(x, y)} & =\left.\frac{\partial \tilde{x}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|_{\left(\frac{x}{y}, \frac{1}{y}\right)}+\left.\frac{\partial \tilde{y}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{\left(\frac{x}{y}, \frac{1}{y}\right)} \\
& =\left.\frac{1}{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|_{\left(\frac{x}{y}, \frac{1}{y}\right)} \\
& =\left.\tilde{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_{(x, y)} & =\left.\frac{\partial \tilde{x}}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}+\left.\frac{\partial \tilde{y}}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})} \\
& =-\left.\frac{x}{y} \frac{1}{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}+-\left.\frac{1}{y^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})} \\
& =-\left.\tilde{x} \tilde{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}-\left.\tilde{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}.
\end{aligned}
$$
So in the second chart, we have the transition map from the first chart as
$$
\begin{aligned}
& x=\tilde{x} y=\frac{\tilde{x}}{\tilde{y}} \quad \text { and } y=\frac{1}{\tilde{y}} \\
& \text { so } \\
& F_* X=-\frac{\tilde{x}}{\tilde{y}}\left(\left.\tilde{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}\right)-\frac{1}{\tilde{y}}\left(-\left.\tilde{x} \tilde{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}-\left.\tilde{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\tilde{x} \tilde{y})}\right) \\
&=-\left.\tilde{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}+\left.\tilde{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}+\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})} \\
&=-\left.\tilde{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}+\left.(\tilde{x}+1) \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}.
\end{aligned}
$$
For the third chart, we have the transition map from the first chart in standard coordiantes
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (x, y) \mapsto\left(\frac{y}{x}, \frac{1}{x}\right)=(\hat{x}, \hat{y}) \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Then $\hat{x}=\frac{y}{x} \quad \hat{y}=\frac{1}{x}$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_{(x, y)} & =\left.\frac{\partial \hat{x}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})}+\left.\frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})} \\
& =-\left.\frac{y}{x^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})}-\left.\frac{1}{x^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})} \\
&=-\left.\hat{x} \hat{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\hat x, \hat y)}-\left.\hat{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_{(x, y)} & =\left.\frac{\partial \hat{x}}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})}+\left.\frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y}}\right|_{(\hat x, \hat y)} \\
& =\left.\frac{1}{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})} \\
& =\left.\hat{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Subsituting these in, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_* X & =\left.x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_{(x, y)}-\left.y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_{(x, y)} \\
& =x\left[-\left.\hat{x} \hat{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})}-\left.\hat{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})}\right]-y\left[\left.\hat{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
and $x=\frac{1}{\hat{y}}, \quad y=\frac{\hat{x}}{\hat{y}}$ so
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_* X & =-\left.\frac{\hat{x} \hat{y}}{\hat{y}} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{\hat{(x, y)}}=\left.\frac{\hat{y}}{\hat{y}} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})}-\left.\frac{\hat{x}}{\hat{y}} \hat{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})} \\
& =-\left.2 \hat{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})}-\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y}}\right|_{(\hat{x}, \hat{y})}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since the push-forward exists in every chart, there is an $F$-related vector field.

It looks like this exercise wants us to show that for this $F$ whose
range does not include the point $[1,1,0]$ at infinity of
$\mathbb {R\,P}^2$  there is a very natural chart $\varphi_1$
which does not lead to any singularities and works for the whole
domain and range of $F\,.$
When we use the other charts $\varphi_2,\varphi_3$ we
cannot get away without terms $1/x^2$ or $1/y^2\,.$
Also: even when we patch together both, the union of their domains does not contain
the point  $[0,0,1]$ and the union of their coordinate ranges does
not contain the origin $(0,0)$ of $\mathbb R^2\,.$
I redo the calculations in what I believe is a simpler notation (did not check all calculations of yours).
The map $F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb {P\,R}^2,(x,y)\mapsto F(x,y)=[x,y,1]\,$ has in the chart
$$\tag1
\varphi([x,y,z])=\left(\frac xz,\frac yz\right)
$$
the differential (Jacobi matrix)
$$\tag2
d(\varphi\circ F)_p=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}\,,\quad p=(x,y)\,,
$$
because $(\varphi\circ F)(x,y)=(x,y)\,.$
In the chart $\varphi\,,$
the pushforward of $X=x\,\partial_y-y\,\partial_x$ (which is in $T\mathbb R^2$) by $F$ is
\begin{align}
(F_*X)_{(\varphi\,\circ\, F)(p)}&=d(\varphi\circ F)_p(X)=\underbrace{\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}\pmatrix{-y\\x}}_{\textstyle {-y\choose x}}\cdot\pmatrix{\partial_x\\\partial_y}_{(\varphi\,\circ\, F)(p)}\\[2mm]\tag3
&=(x\,\partial_y-y\,\partial_x)_{(x,y)}
=x\,\partial_y-y\,\partial_x\,.
\end{align}
I emphasize that this is in $T_{F(p)}\mathbb{P\,R}^2$ and expressed in the first chart $\varphi\,.$
For the second chart
$$\tag4
\varphi([x,y,z])=\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{z}{y}\right)
$$
I use the same symbol $\varphi$ to simplify notation. Then, cutting short,
\begin{align}\tag5
(\varphi\circ F)(x,y)&=\left(\frac xy,\frac 1y\right)\,,&
d(\varphi\circ F)_p&=\pmatrix{\frac 1y&-\frac x{y^2}\\0&-\frac1{y^2}}=\frac{-1}{y^2}\pmatrix{-y&x\\0&1}\,,\end{align}\begin{align}\tag6
(F_*X)_{(\varphi\,\circ\,F)(p)}&=-\tfrac{x^2+y^2}{y^2}\partial_x-\tfrac x{y^2}\,\partial_y\,.
\end{align}
Likewise, for the third chart
\begin{align}\tag7
(\varphi\circ F)(x,y)&=\left(\frac yx,\frac 1x\right)\,,&
d(\varphi\circ F)_p&=\pmatrix{\frac{-y}{x^2}&\frac 1x\\-\frac1{x^2}&0}=\frac{-1}{x^2}\pmatrix{y&-x\\1&0}\,,\end{align}\begin{align}\tag8
(F_*X)_{(\varphi\,\circ\,F)(p)}&=\tfrac{x^2+y^2}{x^2}\partial_x+\tfrac y{x^2}\,\partial_y\,.
\end{align}

Thank you so much! It seems that I got this too, modulo a mistake in the second one. The thing is, I called the changed coordinates $\tilde x$ and $\tilde y$. Then once I wrote everything in terms of these, I didn't have anything like $\frac{1}{\tilde x}$ but I see now that if I didn't introduce the $(\tilde x, \tilde y)$ I would have what you have

Why was this wrong to do?

Are you identifying the tangent basis vectors in the two spaces?

\begin{aligned}
& F_* X=x\left[-\left.\frac{x}{y^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}-\left.\frac{1}{y^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}\right]-y\left[\left.\frac{1}{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}[0])}\right] \
& =\left.\frac{-\left(x^2+y^2\right)}{y^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}-\left.\frac{1}{y^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})} \
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
& =-\left.\left(\tilde{x}^2+1\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}-\left.\tilde{y}^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})}
\end{aligned}
And this looks fine to me when I write it like $(\tilde x, \tilde y)$ but the line above does not look fine as we get $\frac{1}{y^2}$

Let's get to the bottom of this. I have numbered all my equations. Which one does not look fine? It would not be the first sign error.

In fact, it seems like there was a sign error in (6). I corrected it.

I know in differential geometry people use different notation all the time. Right now I'm studying for a final so Im trying to be a bit pedantic. Shouldn't the pullback be entirely in $(\hat x, \hat y)$ coordinates? Since as you have left it, it's still in $(x,y)$ coordinates which are the chart 1 coordinates, but the tangent vectors should be the vectors in chart 2 coordinates

I am not even sure if I qualify as a differential geometer. It is more a hobby of mine. The charts map $\mathbb{P,R^2}$ to the space $\mathbb R^2$ in which our good old coordinates $(x,y)$ live in. I see no problem with that. My final formulas for the pushed-forward vector field are of course only meaningful when we know which chart we used. That exercise makes this very clear. A tip: John M Lee is a member of this forum. I think his username is JackLee. You may want to try to reach out to him.

There are three charts on $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$. They are
$$\varphi_1([x,y,z])=\left(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x}\right).$$
$$\varphi_2([x,y,z])=\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{z}{y}\right)$$
$$\varphi_3([x,y,z])=\left(\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z}\right)$$
We compute $F_*X$ in the first chart. Let $q=[x,y,1]$. Then
$$
\left.F_*X\right|_q
=d_{F^{-1}(q)}F(X_{F^{-1}(q)})
=q_x\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_{q}-\left.q_y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_{q}
 $$
Now the transition map between $\varphi_1$ coordinates and $\varphi_2$ coordinates is
$$\Psi_{1,2}(x,y)=\left(\frac{x}{y}, \frac{1}{y}\right)=(\tilde x, \tilde y).$$
Now we convert to $(\tilde x, \tilde y)$ coordinates.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_{q} & =\left.\left.\frac{\partial \tilde{x}}{\partial x}\right|_q \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|_{\left(\frac{q_x}{q_y}, \frac{1}{q_y}\right)}+\left.\frac{\partial \tilde{y}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{\left(\frac{q_x}{q_y}, \frac{1}{q_y}\right)} \\
& =\left.\frac{1}{q_y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|_{\left(\frac{q_x}{q_y}, \frac{1}{q_y}\right)} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_{q} & =\left.\frac{\partial \tilde{x}}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|_{(\frac{q_x}{q_y}, \frac{1}{q_y})}+\left.\frac{\partial \tilde{y}}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\frac{q_x}{q_y}, \frac{1}{q_y})} \\
& =-\left.\frac{q_x}{q_y^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|_{(\frac{q_x}{q_y}, \frac{1}{q_y})}-\left.\frac{1}{q_y^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\frac{q_x}{q_y}, \frac{1}{q_y})} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
So in the second chart, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \left.F_* X\right|_q=q_x\left[-\left.\frac{q_x}{q_y^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right|_{(\frac{q_x}{q_y}, \frac{1}{q_y})}-\left.\frac{1}{q_y^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}\right|_{(\frac{q_x}{q_y}, \frac{1}{q_y})}\right] - q_y\left[\frac{1}{y}\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde x}\right|_{(\frac{q_x}{q_y}, \frac{1}{q_y})}\right]\\
&=\frac{-(q_x^2+q_y^2)}{q_y^2}\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde x}\right|_{(\frac{q_x}{q_y}, \frac{1}{q_y})} - \frac{1}{q_y^2}\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde y}\right|_{(\frac{q_x}{q_y}, \frac{1}{q_y})}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
For the third chart, we have the transition map
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (x, y) \mapsto\left(\frac{y}{x}, \frac{1}{x}\right)=(\hat{x}, \hat{y}) \\
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_{q} & =\left.\frac{\partial \hat{x}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\frac{q_y}{q_x}, \frac{1}{q_x})}+\left.\frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y}}\right|_{(\frac{q_y}{q_x}, \frac{1}{q_x})} \\
& =-\left.\frac{q_y}{q_x^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\frac{q_y}{q_x}, \frac{1}{q_x})}-\left.\frac{1}{q_x^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y}}\right|_{(\frac{q_y}{q_x}, \frac{1}{q_x})} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_{q} & =\left.\frac{\partial \hat{x}}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\frac{q_y}{q_x}, \frac{1}{q_x})}+\left.\frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y}}\right|_{(\frac{q_y}{q_x}, \frac{1}{q_x})} \\
& =\left.\frac{1}{q_x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{(\frac{q_y}{q_x}, \frac{1}{q_x})} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Subsituting these in, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_* X & =\left.q_x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_{q}-\left.q_y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_{q} \\
& =q_x\left[-\left.\frac{q_y}{q_x^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{\left(\frac{q_y}{q_x}, \frac{1}{q_x}\right)}-\left.\frac{1}{q_x^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y}}\right|_{\left(\frac{q_y}{q_x}, \frac{1}{q_x}\right)}\right]-q_y\left[\left.\frac{1}{q_x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{\left(\frac{q_y}{q_x}, \frac{1}{q_x}\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{-2q_y}{q_x}\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{\left(\frac{q_y}{q_x}, \frac{1}{q_x}\right)}-\frac{1}{q_x}\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x}}\right|_{\left(\frac{q_y}{q_x}, \frac{1}{q_x}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, we see that we need one chart to represent the pushforward in $\phi_1$ coordinates, and two charts to represent the pushforward in $\phi_2$ and $\phi_3$ coordinates.

It would be good for a discussion if you also numbered your formulas. In your notation $q=[x,y,1]$ it must be that $q_x=x$ and $q_y=y,.$ Then the end results of your $F_*X$ for the first and second chart look plausible as they agree formally with mine. The end result for the third chart looks weird. Can you say in one sentence why you use a transition map? I am willing to learn something new.

Also: there is a lot of $x,y$-symmetry in that entire exercise. If we agree on the first and second chart the result for the third cannot be that different.
